# Hide Soft Keyboard on Done Keypress in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I'm struggling with the done button on the soft keyboard. I can't get the soft keyboard Done key press to hide the keyboard. From another button, it works perfectly with

`imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);`

but the onKeyListener does not function the way I want. When I hit the editText, the soft keyboard shows up and its content is cleared from characters.

Thanks for listening!

The main.xml:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/answer" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:textSize="36px"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:minWidth="60dp" android:maxWidth="60dp"
/>
```

The Java file:

```
private EditText editText;
//...
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
editText.setOnClickListener(onKeyboard);
editText.setOnKeyListener(onSoftKeyboardDonePress);
//...

// method not working:
private View.OnKeyListener onSoftKeyboardDonePress=new View.OnKeyListener() 
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)
        {
            // code to hide the soft keyboard
            imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener onKeyboard=new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        editText.setText("");
    }
};
```

The working method using a button (in the same java file):

```
private View.OnClickListener onDone=new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //....
        // code to hide the soft keyboard
        imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    }
};
```

**Edit:** When I press key no "9" the keyboard hides. That's odd.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use android:imeOptions="actionDone", like that:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :)

Comment: not working for me, really weird on the so-called Android programming.

Comment: Worked after I changed `android:inputType="textPerson"` to `android:inputType="text"`.

Answer (score 26):

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

with context being your activity.

Comment: Thanx for your effort! I changed the if-statement to if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) which made it working with the xml-attribute android:inputType="phone". I'll save your answer until next soft keyboard issue. BR -

Answer (score 4):

Changed the if-statement to `if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)` made it working with the xml-attribute `android:inputType="phone"`.

Answer (score 2):

SoftKeyboard can be hide by following way

In Java class we can write following code to hide keyboard when user press done or enter

```
etBid.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                    event != null &&
                            event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                            event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                if (event == null || !event.isShiftPressed())
                {
                    // the user is done typing.
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true; // consume.
                }
            }
            return false; // pass on to other listeners.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at setOnEditorActionListener() for the EditText:

> Set a special listener to be called when an action is performed on the
>   text view. This will be called when the enter key is pressed, or when
>   an action supplied to the IME is selected by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` its work for me.

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_switch_name"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"       
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

<EditText
...
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).