# Close android keyboard when all the fields were entered using keyboard next button?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have 5 edit text fields in my form, I can able to switch to next field using keyboard next button.

once I visit the last field in the form, when user clicks next it is again going to the top filed, here I want to dismiss the keyboard.

can any one help me how to close it

Comment: try to change imeoption to done like
 android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
in your last field and add 
android:imeOptions="actionNext" in your other fields

Comment: Please Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/3422200/4069985

Comment: @AdeelTurk thanks bro! it worked!

Comment: @praneethkumar my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this programmatically, you can use `InputMethodManager()`, as following:

```
int count = 1;
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if(view == R.id.YOUR_FIRST_VIEW_ID && count < 2){
    ++count;
}
else if (view == R.id.YOUR_FIRST_VIEW_ID && count == 2) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

So when you are on your first edit box, 2nd time `count = 2`, then hide the keyboard.